# Scroll to bottom of DIV element

Tags: jquery, scroll

I’ve seen countless posts on this one and tried them all, but none seem to work and I don't know why.

Basically, I load a SQL generated HTML page into a div, and try to scroll to the bottom of it. Hours later, still I can't figure it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#chat_grab').load('chat_grab.php');
        $('#chat_grab').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat_grab')[0].scrollHeight}, 800);
    });
</script>

<div id="chat_grab" style="height: 152px; overflow-y: auto"></div>
```

It doesn't scroll to the bottom of the page. Like I said, I've tried multiple variants of the scroll line found on here.

---

I tried this, but still no luck;

```
$('#chat_grab').load('chat_grab.php', callback);

function callback() {
    $('#chat_grab').scrollTop(0);
}
```

Comment: Try using a callback to animate the page, you might be experiencing a race condition. $Load offers a success callback for this purpose.

Comment: I've edited topic, is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work either. Something must be conflicting in my code :(

Comment: Once the load has occurred, try running the jQuery you are using to scroll directly in the console, does it work? Put a console log into the callback, ensure it is being executed. Eliminate some of the obvious possibilities and at the very least you should be left with some more specific questions to ask.

Comment: So i just got it working if I run it directly from the page, but the page is also in its own div, and it doesn't work then. I'll update post

Comment: "The page is also in it's own div" sounds a bit odd, it sounds like you might need an iframe. If chat_grab.php is a fully qualified webpage then loading it inside a div is going to result in unexpected behaviour

Comment: Oh its a chat popup. I click the chat button on the main site, and it pops up a hidden div which loads chat.php, as above

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
   scrollTop: $('#chat_grab').offset().top - 100
 }, 800);
```

Comment: Feel free to change the offset value (100) to correct the scroll position.